# How to optimize the nested for loop with different lengths?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, for-loop, .net-core

I'm need to optimize 2 nested for loops using LINQ or Zip in c#, Because this code taking some time to load.

> These two lists are loaded with api calls

```
List<OrderIncidentsDto> orderDtos = new List<OrderIncidentsDto>();
List<OrderItemDto> orderItemDtos = new List<OrderItemDto>();
```

I am trying iterate this data using two nested for loops

```
for (int incidents = 0; incidents < orderDtos.Count; incidents++) 
{
        var oItems = new List<OrderItemDto>();
    for (int items = 0; items < orderItemDtos.Count; items++)
    {
        if (orderItemDtos[items].IncidentNumber == orderDtos[incidents].OrderIncidentName)
        {
            oItems.Add(orderItemDtos[items]);
            orderDtos[incidents].OrderItems = oItems;
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest me the best way to reduce the lines of code or get rid multiple loops.

Comment: How long does it take to run? How many items are in each list (do not guess)?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Have a look at [Grouped Joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-grouped-joins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code has a time complexity of `O(n^2)` this can be reduced to `O(n)` by first indexing `orderItemDtos` by `IncidentNumber` and then just looping over the `orderDtos` picking out their order items

```
var orderItemLookup = orderItemDtos.ToLookup(x => x.IncidentNumber);
orderDtos.ForEach(order => order.OrderItems = orderItemLookup[order.OrderIncidentName]);
```